# How to make calculations based on duplicate values in different columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a database concerning a certain production line.
At the end of the production line, a tracability picture is taken of each product, logging the serial number of the product and the timestamp of that picture. I'm trying to add a column with the mean value of the timestamps, if the date on which the picture was taken, and the model, are the same.

Basically, I would like to group the data based on duplicates in the model AND date column, and make calculations (mean, dev) for the delta data for each group.

https://paste.pics/bc4a8d473a8df5e543ef980511c555ef

As you can see here, column B consists of the model nr, and column C is the date the stamp was made

What I want to do is;
If a group of rows has the same value for MODEL, AND, the same value for DATE:
Calculate the mean of Column E for the data in that group of rows

At this moment, I have no idea how to group the data.

```
dim Modelnrs as range
Dim DateStamp as range
Dim deltaStamp as range

set modelnrs = range("B1",range("B1").end(xldown))
Set datestamp = range("C1",range("C1").end(xldown))
set deltastamp = range("E1", range("E1").end(xldown))

for each cl in modelnrs
if cl.offset(1,0).value = cl.value AND cl.offset(1,1) = cl.offset(0,1)
then
group.add cl.entirerow



' with each group, calculate mean of column E for group
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could use PivotTables to group your data by Model and Date, and then make an average with field TimeStamp to get the mean value.

Comment: Thank you! That could be one way to solve it, i like overcomplicating things :-)